# How to have a direction with a destination address (Google maps API)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic4, google-directions-api

i want to make a direction with Google Maps API but it didn't work with an address. I tried to use Geocoding Services like that but it don't know the 'route'(Direction Services).

My method :

```js
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
           geocoder.geocode({'address': this.nomBar}, function(results, status) {
             this.directionsService.route({
               origin: this.currentLocation,
               destination: results[0].geometry.location,
               travelMode: 'DRIVING'
             }, (response, status) => {
               if (status === 'OK') {
                 that.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
               } else {
                 window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
               }
             });
           });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the Geocoder in order to get directions from an origin and a destination. Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests) states:

> `origin` (required) specifies the start location from which to
>   calculate directions. This value may be specified as a `String` (for
>   example, "Chicago, IL"), as a `LatLng` value or as a `google.maps.Place`
>   object. If you use a `google.maps.Place` object, you can specify a place
>   ID, a query string or a `LatLng` location.
>
> `destination` (required) specifies the end location to which to
>   calculate directions. The options are the same as for the origin field
>   described above.

This [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel) uses addresses:

```
directionsService.route({
  origin: start, // e.g. "chicago, il"
  destination: end, // e.g. "st louis, mo"
  travelMode: 'DRIVING'
}, function(response, status) {
  if (status === 'OK') {
    directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
  } else {
    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
  }
});
```

While this other [example](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-travel-modes) uses coordinates:

```
directionsService.route({
  origin: {lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447},
  destination: {lat: 37.768, lng: -122.511},
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
}, function(response, status) {
  if (status == 'OK') {
    directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
  } else {
    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!